# UML Activity Diagram - how do I model nested Ifs

Tags: oop, uml, modeling, activity-diagram

I'm trying to model a UML Activity Diagram for a medical appointment process. At some point the health center needs to confirm the patient's assistance, in which point the patient can choose whether to confirm their assistance, re-schedule the appointment, or cancel it. I'm using a decision node with a "is going to assist?" statement, so the two logical paths are 'yes' and 'no'. If the answer is yes, then the process continues, but if it is no instead, then there's another decision node "is going to re-schedule?".

Can a flow go from one decision node to another? If not, what should I do in this case?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: @JohnSaunders you must be really fun at parties.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that since everybody would understand its meaning.

According to Superstructures 2.5

> A DecisionNode is a ControlNode that chooses between outgoing ActivityEdges for the routing of tokens.

and one of the constraints:

> zero_input_parameters:
>   If the DecisionNode has no decisionInputFlow and an incoming ControlFlow, then any decisionInput Behavior has no in parameters.